# Flink CSV connector handle faulty messages

Tags: apache-flink

I am going through https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/formats/csv/. Here we have an option to enable `csv.ignore-parse-errors`. Is there any way, we can put faulty messages in DLQ topic.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible with any of the built-in connectors and formats. You would have to use the DataStream API to implement a ProcessFunction that does the parsing itself and sends faulty records to a side output.